# Recover a lost LibreOffice document

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, libreoffice

I was working in LibreOffice Writer with an .odt document yesterday, was saving it regularly, but today it looks like I did nothing! I think, the reason is in me accidantally saving it in /tmp all the time (according to Recently opened documents in LO). I recovered all files from /tmp using testdisk, but couldn't find anything, that would look like an edited file, only the old version. Automatic backup was off :( Turned it on now.

Any ideas, what other options I might have to recover the file?

I use Ubuntu 13.04 x64 (russian locale), LO 4.0.2.2.

PS

Initially posted it on ask.libreoffice.org (http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/29757/recover-a-lost-document/), but it seems less active, than StackExchange community.

Comment: If you recovered the files, and you were unable to recover the document, then it sounds like you are out of luck.  Despite the fact the website looks similar its not a SE website.

Comment: Ramhound, so there is no other possible way?

Yeah, I know it is not a SE website, that's exactly what I meant.